# How to process a space delimited environment variable with xargs

Tags: xargs

I am trying to execute a long running process multiple times in parallel.  The parameter for each execution of the process is stored in a space separated environment variable.  Here is a contrived example of what I am trying to execute:

```
$ echo -e 1 2 3 4 | xargs --max-procs=3 --max-args=1 --replace=% echo % is the number being processed
```

Here is the output from that command:

```
1 2 3 4 is the number being processed
```

Why is max-args seemingly ignored?  I then tried to explicitly set the delimiter which gives better results:

```
$ echo -e 1 2 3 4 | xargs -d " " --max-procs=3 --max-args=1 --replace=% echo % is the number being processed
1 is the number being processed
2 is the number being processed
3 is the number being processed
4
 is the number being processed
```

What is xargs doing when it processes the 4th argument?

After some searching, I did manage to almost get what I want.  The arguments are processed correctly, but parallelism does not work (verified with another command not shown here):

```
$ echo -e 1 2 3 4 | xargs -n 1 | xargs --max-procs=3 --max-args=1 --replace=% echo % is the number being processed
1 is the number being processed
2 is the number being processed
3 is the number being processed
4 is the number being processed
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does

```
echo -e 1 2 3 4 | sed -e 's/\s\+/\n/g' | xargs --max-procs=3 --max-args=1 --replace=% echo % is the number being processed
```

accomplish the task? The output seems about right:

```
1 is the number being processed
2 is the number being processed
3 is the number being processed
4 is the number being processed
```

I also tried replacing `echo` with `sleep` to confirm it executes in parallel, and it does:

```
echo -e 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 | sed -e 's/\s\+/\n/g' | xargs --max-procs=20 --max-args=1 --replace=% sleep 1
```

Comment: Thanks, that definitely works.  For curiosity's sake, do you know why it is necessary to replace white space with a newline?  I'm a xargs newbie.

Comment: Not quite sure about that, could be a bug/feature of xargs. The `man` page for xargs barely hints on this behaviour, suggesting usage of null character as a separator to solve this problem (`-0` option).

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK the default input delimter of xargs is \r , so you have to change it to <space> and send your input ending accordingly, like so:

```
$ echo -n "1 2 3 4 " | xargs -d" " --max-procs=3 --max-args=1 --replace=% echo % is the number being processed
1 is the number being processed
2 is the number being processed
3 is the number being processed
4 is the number being processed
$
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Some other ways, maybe simpler, also with `-n`, `-max-args`:

```sh
echo -n "foo bar baz" | tr ' ' '\n' | xargs -n 1 echo    # With \n, no need for -0
echo -n "foo bar baz" | tr ' ' '\0' | xargs -0 -n 1 echo # Using null character
echo -n "foo bar baz" | xargs -d ' ' -n 1 echo           # Telling to xargs the delimiter
```

- Where of course `echo` could be any command you want.
- See also `-L` parameter and `-d '\n'` (if lines with spaces).
- Process win parallel with `--max-procs` or maybe better with [`parallel`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/).